# Nexus 7 USB Host - Not able to enumerate device

Tags: android, usb

I recently bought a Nexus 7 for USB development.  I would like to use the USB Host functionality provided by the new Android OS.  I was following the USB Host Tutorial at the link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html.

My program is very simple, and here are the relevant parts of the code:

```
private UsbManager manager;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.i(TAG, "in onCreate()");
    manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    if(manager==null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "USB Manager is NULL");
    }
    else {
        Log.i(TAG, "USB Manager = " + manager);
    }
}

public void enumerateUSBDevices() {
    HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
    Collection<UsbDevice> deviceCollection = deviceList.values();
    Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceCollection.iterator();
    Log.i(TAG, "Number of connected USB Devices = " + deviceCollection.size());
    while(deviceIterator.hasNext()){
        UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();
        Log.i(TAG, device.getDeviceName());
    }
}
```

When the enumerateUSBDevices function is called, it reports that the number of connected USB Devices = 0.  I am using a USB OTG cable, and I know that the Nexus 7 is powering the connected USB Device because I plugged in a USB Mouse, and it works properly.  I also plugged in another Android phone, and the Nexus 7 was confirmed to be powering the device.  However, in both of these instances, the Android program says that there are no USB devices connected.  I am unsure what is going wrong in my code.  In my Android manifest, I have the following line:

```
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
```

My manifest does not have any intent filters associated with any USB devices.  My understanding based on reading the tutorials is that the intent filters need to be in the Manifest only if you want the APP to be notified when the USB device is connected after the App is running?

Can anybody shed light into what I may be doing wrong?  Do I need to root my device?

Thanks,

Comment: You should not need to root your device to use the official USB host APIs on a device which supports them (as the Nexus 7 obviously does).  Perhaps it would be worth checking your assumption that device filters are not needed, by adding one.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, that since the Android OS takes over the mouse.  I plugged in a different USB device and the code worked fine.